# Почему вылетает ошибка при get запросе

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Пытаюсь получить данные от апи через гет запрос:

```
https://currate.ru/api/?get=currency_list&key=5556c4fe4eea37cbea8e6fec6240b5a5
```

Но возвращает:

> D/MainActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Код:

APIClient.java

```
package com.ss.retrofitlesson;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

class APIClient {
    private static String BASE_URL = "https://currate.ru/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    static Retrofit getClient(){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

APIInterface.java

```
package com.ss.retrofitlesson;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface APIInterface {
    @GET("api/?get=currency_list&key=5556c4fe4eea37cbea8e6fec6240b5a5")
    Call<List<Currencies>> getCurrencies();
}
```

Currencies.java

```
package com.ss.retrofitlesson;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Currencies {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<String> data = null;

    public Currencies(String status, String message, List<String> data){
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Currencies{" +
                "status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ss.retrofitlesson;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Currencies> currenciesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currenciesList = new ArrayList<>();
        APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

        Call<List<Currencies>> call = apiInterface.getCurrencies();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Currencies>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Currencies>> call, Response<List<Currencies>> response) {
                currenciesList = response.body();
                Log.d("MainActivity", currenciesList.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Currencies>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ss.retrofitlesson">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `Call<List<Currencies>> getCurrencies();` замените на `Call<Currencies> getCurrencies();` (Файл APIInterface)

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена :)

Comment: Будет классно, если Вы сумеете объяснить причину ошибки, по каким признакам можно найти решение, и - выложите это все здесь как ответ) И Вам большее понимание, и другим будет проще)